# To install kudu do we required java to be installed?

Tags: java, apache-kudu

To install the Apache kudu do we required java as prequisite? i am planning to install kudu in separate VM what are all the prequisite

Answer (score 0):

You need JDK 7 or JDK 8 to build it. Also take a look to the OS Requirements.

As you can read in the [Apache Kudu Prerequisites and Requirements](https://kudu.apache.org/docs/installation.html#_prerequisites_and_requirements):

> ***Operating System Requirements***
>
> **Linux:**
>
> RHEL 6, RHEL 7, CentOS 6, CentOS 7, Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty), Ubuntu
>   16.04 (Xenial), Debian 8 (Jessie), or SLES 12.
>
> A kernel and filesystem that support hole punching. Hole punching is
>   the use of the fallocate(2) system call with the FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE
>   option set. See troubleshooting hole punching for more information.
>
> **macOS:**
>
> OS X 10.10 Yosemite, OS X 10.11 El Capitan, macOS Sierra, or macOS
>   High Sierra.
>
> Prebuilt macOS packages are not provided.
>
> **Windows:**
>
> Microsoft Windows is unsupported.
>
> **Java:**
>
> *JDK 7 or JDK 8 is required to build Kudu, but a JRE is not required at runtime except for tests.*